# How to correctly close resources?

Tags: java, exception

I have methods that all propagate exceptions and then I have handling on one place, however I realized something.

Let's say I have method like this

```
public void foo() throws Exception e {
  Statement stmt = createStatement();
  doSomething(stmt);
  stmt.close();
}
```

My issue is that if exception is thrown by doSometing() method the statement will not be closed, but I don't want to handle exception there. Is the right approach to have try and catch that only rethrows exception and finally to close statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void foo() throws Exception e {

  Statement stmt = null ; 
  try {
    stmt = createStatement();
    doSomething(stmt);
  } finally {
    if(stmt != null) 
      stmt.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Close it in finally block. All resources opened should be released/closed. 
See this for more - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03216.html

Answer (score 1):

Modification to [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) answer.  You actually may initialize **stmt** before try block.  That way there is no need to see if it's `null`, so this just suffice:

```
public void foo() throws Exception e {

  final Statement stmt = createStatemnt( );

  try {
    doSomething(stmt);
  } finally {
    stmt.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can throw the exception further

```
try {
   stmt = createStatement();
   doSomething(stmt);
}
 catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
finally {
   if(stmt != null) 
      stmt.close();
}
```

Comment: no need to add that catch block as the method already declares that throws Exception. You can have a try-finally block with no catch

Comment: Why would you bother catching and rethrowing here?  try ... finally works fine without a rethrow.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20.2

Comment: I missed out the throws in the signature, I thought the question was If it was valid to throw an exception further in the catch block.