# try-with-resources Statement in Java SE 7 and later

Tags: java, io, try-with-resources

I'm using Java SDK8 and I created an inputStream and outputStream objects.

Prior to Java SE 7, I could use a finally block to ensure that these resources are closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or not.
I read that in Java SE 7 and later I can use a try-with-resources statement and in case the resource I'm using implements the interface java.lang.AutoCloseable I don't need to close this resource in the finally block any more.

My questions are:
1. Is it correct that if I'm using a resource that implements the interface java.lang.AutoCloseable I don't need to close it in the finally block and it will be closed even if an exception will be thrown? if so, Is there a precondition that must exist? (e.g. creating the resource inside a try block?)
2. What does the try-with-resources statement exactly mean?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: related: [Try-with-resources equivalent in Java 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611940/try-with-resources-equivalent-in-java-1-6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java7 try-with-resources Statement advantage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739362/java7-try-with-resources-statement-advantage)

Comment: A few clicks would have given you the answer

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is it correct that if I'm using a resource that implements the interface java.lang.AutoCloseable I don't need to close it in the finally block and it will be closed even if an exception will be thrown?

Yes.

> if so, Is there a precondition that must exist? (e.g. creating the resource inside a try block?)

The resource must be created within the try-with-resources statement (see below).

> 2. What does the try-with-resources statement exactly mean?

Here's a try-with-resources statement:

```
try (FileReader fr = FileReader(path)) {
    // use fr here
}
```

Note how the initialization of the `FileReader` is **in** the `try` (in the new `()` part). That's how the statement knows what needs to be closed later.

(More in [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), though I don't like their first example because it relies on A) The fact that the `BufferedReader` constructor never throws, and B) The fact that `BufferedReader` will close the `FileReader` when the `BufferedReader` is closed. Those are true for `BufferedReader`, but it's a poor example in the general case.)

The full gritty details, including a translation of what a `try-with-resources` looks like in the old `try/catch/finally` format, are in [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3).

Note that you can create multiple resources in the statement; they're closed in reverse order of creation:

```
try (
    FileReader fr =
         new FileReader(fileName);
    NiftyThingUsingReader nifty =
         new NiftyThingUsingReader(fr)
) {
    // ...use `nifty` here
}
```

Although you *could* write:

```
try (
    NiftyThingUsingReader nifty =
         new NiftyThingUsingReader(new FileReader(fileName))
) {
    // ...use `nifty` here
}
```

...you'd have to know **for sure** that `NiftyThingUsingReader(FileReader)` never throws an exception, and that `NiftyThingUsingReader#close` will close the underlying `FileReader`, because it will **not** be handled by the try-with-resources itself. If you're unsure, keep them separate, so that the try-with-resources statement closes the `FileReader` even if the `NiftyThingUsingReader(FileReader)` constructor throws, and even if `NiftyThingUsingReader#close` doesn't close it.

The resources don't have to be relying on each other (directly); for instance, this is a fairly common situation where you want both the input and output to be handled:

```
try (
    java.util.zip.ZipFile zf =
         new java.util.zip.ZipFile(zipFileName);
    java.io.BufferedWriter writer = 
        java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset)
) {
    // Enumerate each entry
    for (java.util.Enumeration entries =
                            zf.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements();) {
        // Get the entry name and write it to the output file
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String zipEntryName =
             ((java.util.zip.ZipEntry)entries.nextElement()).getName() +
             newLine;
        writer.write(zipEntryName, 0, zipEntryName.length());
    }
}
```