# SonarQube keeps complaining about Use try-with-resources or close this "PreparedStatement" in a "finally" clause

Tags: java, sql, sonarqube, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get an email from a table based on the user's id. However, SonarQube keeps complaining about `Use try-with-resources or close this "PreparedStatement" in a "finally" clause` which I already have.
I've looked at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782647/how-to-correctly-close-resources) and other places but the solutions don't work for me.
Here's the code:

```java
public String getUserEmail(String id) throws SQLException {
        String emailAddress = null;
        String sql = "select email from my_table where id=?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
        try {
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                emailAddress = rs.getString("email");
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new TuringClientException("Failed to getUserEmail. ", e);
        } finally {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
        return emailAddress;
    }
```

I've also try wrapping `PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql)` in another try catch or do nested try-catch but none of the attempts works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,java.lang.String)) may throw an `SQLException`. If the statement is successfully prepared and then `setString` throws an exception, it will do so **outside** of the `try` block and the statement will never be closed. Moving the `prepareStatement` into a nested `try` should be OK, as long as you have the `clsoe` in the right `finally` block (and without seeing what you did it's hard to say why SonarQube is complaining about it), but honestly, using the try-with-resource syntax would just be so much neater. Note, by the way, that the `ResultSet` should also be closed:

```
public String getUserEmail(String id) throws SQLException {
    String emailAddress = null;
    String sql = "select email from my_table where id=?";
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
        try (ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                emailAddress = rs.getString("email");
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new TuringClientException("Failed to getUserEmail. ", e);
        }
    }
    return emailAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try (try with resources)

```
public String getUserEmail(String id) throws SQLException {
        String emailAddress = null;
        String sql = "select email from my_table where id=?";
        try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                emailAddress = rs.getString("email");
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new TuringClientException("Failed to getUserEmail. ", e);
        }
        return emailAddress;
    }
```